# No internet connection on Debian 12

Tags: debian, networking, kde

I installed Debian two days ago. While installing the network was fine, everything was correct. On the first boot however, I got greeted with errors like "IP configuration was unavailable", "Couldn't connect to Wired connection 1", and similars. I am writing this using USB tethering. I don't know what's wrong, it just sort of happened.

Here are some useful commands:

`sudo dmesg | grep -i 'r8169'`: (r8169 being my ethernet driver):

```
[    3.042315] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: RTL8168g/8111g, b4:2e:99:92:e0:a1, XID 4c0, IRQ 37
[    3.042322] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9194 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    3.046476] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: renamed from eth0
[    8.827167] r8169 0000:04:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw
[    8.852380] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-400:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-400:00, irq=MAC)
[    9.013339] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Down
[   10.581691] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   10.583868] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   56.049359] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   56.062246] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[  101.049573] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
```

`sudo ifconfig enp4s0`:

```
enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b4:2e:99:92:e0:a1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 714  bytes 110249 (107.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

(This one was while trying to connect, but the only difference is the extra byte (It was 713 before)).
`nmcli device show enp4s0`:

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp4s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         B4:2E:99:92:E0:A1
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          70 (connecting (getting IP configuration))
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Home
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/41
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

`sudo journalctl -xb`: [Here](https://0x0.st/HVQW.txt)

- The problem is persistent on Ubuntu, and I do have installed all drivers and firmware for the hardware.

`tcpdump -v -ni enp4s0`:

```
tcpdump: listening on enp4s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
14:55:13.430559 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from b4:2e:99:92:e0:a1, length 300, xid 0x560a8511, Flags [none]
          Client-Ethernet-Address b4:2e:99:92:e0:a1
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Discover
            Hostname (12), length 6: "Debian"
            Parameter-Request (55), length 17: 
              Subnet-Mask (1), BR (28), Time-Zone (2), Default-Gateway (3)
              Domain-Name (15), Domain-Name-Server (6), Unknown (119), Hostname (12)
              Netbios-Name-Server (44), Netbios-Scope (47), MTU (26), Classless-Static-Route (121)
              NTP (42), Classless-Static-Route-Microsoft (249), Static-Route (33), Unknown (252)
              RP (17)
14:55:20.776321 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from b4:2e:99:92:e0:a1, length 300, xid 0x560a8511, secs 7, Flags [none]
          Client-Ethernet-Address b4:2e:99:92:e0:a1
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Discover
            Hostname (12), length 6: "Debian"
            Parameter-Request (55), length 17: 
              Subnet-Mask (1), BR (28), Time-Zone (2), Default-Gateway (3)
              Domain-Name (15), Domain-Name-Server (6), Unknown (119), Hostname (12)
              Netbios-Name-Server (44), Netbios-Scope (47), MTU (26), Classless-Static-Route (121)
              NTP (42), Classless-Static-Route-Microsoft (249), Static-Route (33), Unknown (252)
              RP (17)
14:55:27.870175 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from b4:2e:99:92:e0:a1, length 300, xid 0x560a8511, secs 14, Flags [none]
          Client-Ethernet-Address b4:2e:99:92:e0:a1
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Discover
            Hostname (12), length 6: "Debian"
            Parameter-Request (55), length 17: 
              Subnet-Mask (1), BR (28), Time-Zone (2), Default-Gateway (3)
              Domain-Name (15), Domain-Name-Server (6), Unknown (119), Hostname (12)
              Netbios-Name-Server (44), Netbios-Scope (47), MTU (26), Classless-Static-Route (121)
              NTP (42), Classless-Static-Route-Microsoft (249), Static-Route (33), Unknown (252)
              RP (17)
14:55:36.534243 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from b4:2e:99:92:e0:a1, length 300, xid 0x560a8511, secs 23, Flags [none]
          Client-Ethernet-Address b4:2e:99:92:e0:a1
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Discover
            Hostname (12), length 6: "Debian"
            Parameter-Request (55), length 17: 
              Subnet-Mask (1), BR (28), Time-Zone (2), Default-Gateway (3)
              Domain-Name (15), Domain-Name-Server (6), Unknown (119), Hostname (12)
              Netbios-Name-Server (44), Netbios-Scope (47), MTU (26), Classless-Static-Route (121)
              NTP (42), Classless-Static-Route-Microsoft (249), Static-Route (33), Unknown (252)
              RP (17)
14:55:47.137530 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from b4:2e:99:92:e0:a1, length 300, xid 0x560a8511, secs 34, Flags [none]
          Client-Ethernet-Address b4:2e:99:92:e0:a1
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Discover
            Hostname (12), length 6: "Debian"
            Parameter-Request (55), length 17: 
              Subnet-Mask (1), BR (28), Time-Zone (2), Default-Gateway (3)
              Domain-Name (15), Domain-Name-Server (6), Unknown (119), Hostname (12)
              Netbios-Name-Server (44), Netbios-Scope (47), MTU (26), Classless-Static-Route (121)
              NTP (42), Classless-Static-Route-Microsoft (249), Static-Route (33), Unknown (252)
              RP (17)
14:55:58.774372 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from b4:2e:99:92:e0:a1, length 300, xid 0xbe1cac50, Flags [none]
          Client-Ethernet-Address b4:2e:99:92:e0:a1
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Discover
            Hostname (12), length 6: "Debian"
            Parameter-Request (55), length 17: 
              Subnet-Mask (1), BR (28), Time-Zone (2), Default-Gateway (3)
              Domain-Name (15), Domain-Name-Server (6), Unknown (119), Hostname (12)
              Netbios-Name-Server (44), Netbios-Scope (47), MTU (26), Classless-Static-Route (121)
              NTP (42), Classless-Static-Route-Microsoft (249), Static-Route (33), Unknown (252)
              RP (17)
```

Comment: this is but a guess, but you need to enable the non-free repos and install the firmware package

Comment: I tried installing `firmware-linux` and `firmware-realtek`. Nothing changed. I also tried booting Ubuntu (Thinking it had to do something with Debian itself). Still nothing.

Comment: these would be important information that you should have in your question, not just in the comments!

Comment: As general state is 70 (Getting IP config) my guess is that you don't have a DHClient installed.

Comment: Doesn't NetworkManager have one embedded?

Comment: @AndroGR it should. The thing is, it's stuck on DHCP. You should follow this lead. Trying running some `dhclient` commands, for instance: `dhclient enp4s0`, and check `tcpdump` output for DHCP. There are many tutorials and documents helping with debugging and investigating DHCP issues.

Comment: @aviro The first one does nothing, no output, no finishing, like it's stuck in an infinite loop. tcpdump on the other side does say stuff about `DHCPDISCOVER` (Which I've read means "Get me an IP address please") but the router completely ignores it. I will edit the post to show the command itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As frustrating as that may sound, it was not an issue with the computer or anything else. Quite surprisingly the router itself had bugged out and wouldn't let my computer have an IP address!

The way to fix it is rather annoying but it worked for me:

- Unplug literally everything from the router and the ethernet cable from your computer. When I say everything I mean literally anything that could be touching the router.
- Restart NetworkManager and networking:

```bash
sudo service networking restart && sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

- Wait a minute or two, just to be sure.
- Finally, reconnect everything back. When the router is fully up, attempt reconnecting. At some point it should say that it succesfully connected.

Comment: NOPE. My fresh install (just done tonight; well, yesterday at this point, I started at 4pm and now it's 8am of my 10th consecutive day spent trying to get this blasted thing working) of debian12, from the official live install disk, does not have a `networking` service or `NetworkManager`. It doesn't know what they are, it just gives errors. This thing is the devil. The buggiest, least reliable, worst documented OS I've ever seen by a country mile.